# Molecule converge ignores role

Tags: ansible, molecule

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why `molecule converge` completely ignores a role that works under normal circumstances. My `converge.yml` file looks like this

```
---
- name: Converge
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - role: appname
      become: true
      become_user: username
    - role: appname_sudo
      become: true
```

Converge runs the `appname_sudo` role but skips the `appname` role completely. Furthermore, when I rename the skipped role it works. So it must be related to the name somehow.

`MOLECULE_DEBUG=1` does not show any output indicating why the role is skipped and both roles work when run in a playbook with `ansible`.

Under what circumstances would `molecule` completely ignore a role like this?